# Is there any Class Based View for Bottle

Tags: python, bottle, django-class-based-views

I wanted something like flask classy but for bottle. Cannot change framework because its been very a lot of plugins written for bottle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple options, either you write your own CBV as mentioned in link to tailor your needs/requirements
 http://reliablybroken.com/b/2010/12/class-based-views-for-bottle/

OR there is a python package bottleCBV https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BottleCBV/0.2